# Having issues when HTML5 loads video in IE11-Invalid Source, and in Safari-Missing Plugin

Tags: html, safari

We are learning to use HTML5, CSS, and CSS3. If you are able to help me with this, please be as specific as you can be, and please include a couple of screen-shots if possible.

I coded my HTML5 with an embedded video so that it shows a poster image of the video at first (before I embed the video with the  tag. Before, and after, I embed the video it displays an invalid source. This ONLY happens in IE and Safari (safari says missing plugin). I have IE11, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox installed but only have issues in IE and Safari. Tested good in Chrome and Firefox. For whatever reason, in Safari it says missing plugin. All of this, on top of the "Invalid Source" for IE11. Any help is greatly appreciated! I've attached the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Lighthouse Cruise</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <h1>Lighthouse Cruise</h1>
    <style>
    video { width: 100%; height: auto; max-width: 320px; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <video controls="controls" poster="lighthouse.jpg">
        <source src="lighthouse.mv4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="lighthouse.ogv" type="video/ogg">
            <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
            src="lighthouse.swf"
            quality="high"
            width="320" height="240"
            title="Door County Lighthouse Cruise">
    </video>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I never really expected to post a question, and then come back to it 9 hours later only to answer myself lol. So, here's the solution:

Note the mv4 extension in the first source element. I corrected it to read, m**4**v. Everything works fine after I load the blocked content. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the exact same issue. Come to find out that IE was using compatibility mode and emulating IE 7.

Putting `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` right after `<head>` fixed this issue for me.